# Reinstall ubuntu-desktop without installing PipeWire?

Tags: pulseaudio, 23.10, pipewire

I prefer to use Pulse Audio as my gaming laptop (2021 TUF Gaming A15) has audio crackling issues with Pipewire, usually with a game open at the same time. when I remove Pipewire `sudo apt remove pipewire` it seems to remove the `ubuntu-desktop` package along with Pipewire, after running `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` (to reinstall the Ubuntu desktop) PulseAudio takes place and there is no audio crackling, but after a reboot Pipewire takes over again.

I am also using the X11 display server, with a dedicated RTX 3050 graphics card and Ryzen 7  4800H processor.

Is it possible to replace the Pipewire service with PulseAudio or remove it without removing the Ubuntu desktop along with it?

Comment: It is Ubuntu 23.10. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Pipewire became default for 23.04 & later; so not having it installed would **not** be recommended, but not using it as I recall was possible (*it was tested in the lunar or 23.04 cycle as I recall*)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ubuntu 23.10 requires PipeWire to be installed. However you can disable it for your user account and install PulseAudio, even though it's not officially recommended:

```bash
sudo apt install pulseaudio

systemctl --user mask pipewire pipewire-pulse pipewire-pulse.socket pipewire.socket wireplumber
systemctl --user enable pulseaudio
reboot
```